# Are Interested and Not Interested still options in Careers 2.0?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

When I get an email from Careers 2.0, it says

> [Redacted] viewed your profile and sent you a message.
>
> Click here to view your message [link redacted]
>
> To reply, click on the link above. Writing a response is optional: if you want, you can just indicate "Interested" or "Not Interested".

How do I indicate "Interested" or "Not Interested"? The only actions I can see are "reply and "view-profile". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can indicate interested or not interested by clicking the link in the email to view the message and replying using the interface on the site.

EDIT

---

More clarification: in the interface on the site, you can submit the first reply without adding additional text to the response.  In the case you just want to say "sure, tell me more", just select interested and submit the reply.  In the case you want to say "no thanks", select not interested and submit the reply.  In the not interested case we provide you with a few options to select the reason you are not interested.  We keep this additional information internal to use for product development.

Comment: yes but the email says writing a response is optional so is there a way to indicate I am interested without writing a response?

Comment: @kush i have edited the answer to give some more detail.

Comment: @kush out of curiosity, did you click any of the links in the email?

Comment: My mistake. The interested and not interested options don't show up until I hit reply. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably you are missing a check box or a botton somewhere outside the mail, in your e-mail-program. In the upper part of your mail??